# How to remove alternative NetBIOS name

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, netbios

We renamed a Windows 2008 R2 x64 server.

We renamed it by running

```
 netdom computername oldname /add:newname
 netdom computername oldname /makeprimary:newname
 netdom computername newname /remove:oldname
```

REF: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc835082.aspx

This was done in a staged manor over a couple of days with reboot's and other configuration changes to keep services up as much as possible while changing the server's name. From the point of view of active directory everything worked. The object in users and computers has changed name, their is no reference to oldname in the AD Database (I spent hours searching in ADSIEdit) and the DNS records are correct. We have even checked the system name table with

```
C:\Windows\system32>netdom computername newname /enumerate:ALLNAMES
All of the names for the computer are:

newname.ourdomain.local
The command completed successfully.
```

and this shows the single new name :)

However.....
The server still responds over netbios to the oldname and the newname. We tracked this back by doing a network capture and proving that it was responding to the old name. After that we ran

```
C:\Windows\system32>nbtstat.exe -n

OURDOMAIN:
Node IpAddress: [10.x.y.z] Scope Id: []

                NetBIOS Local Name Table

       Name               Type         Status
    ---------------------------------------------
    NEWNAME     <00>  UNIQUE      Registered
    OURDOMAIN   <00>  GROUP       Registered
    NEWNAME     <20>  UNIQUE      Registered
    OLDNAME     <20>  UNIQUE      Registered
```

outputs modified for obvious reasons.

We have looked in the registry and neither of the following keys contain the oldname

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\LanmanServer\Parameters\OptionalNames
or
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\ComputerName\ComputerName
```

EDIT:
In response to a great idea from @Rex

```
setspn -L newname
Registered ServicePrincipalNames for CN=NEWNAME,OU=Servers,OU=Site1,DC=ourdomain,DC=local:
    SMTPSVC/NEWNAME
    SMTPSVC/newname.ourdomain.local
    TERMSRV/NEWNAME
    TERMSRV/newname.ourdomain.local
    WSMAN/NEWNAME
    WSMAN/newname.ourdomain.local
    RestrictedKrbHost/NEWNAME
    HOST/NEWNAME
    RestrictedKrbHost/newname.ourdomain.local
    HOST/newname.ourdomain.local
```

This is puzzling. Does anyone know how to remove OLDNAME from the systems netbios identity?
Or even any way to progress our diagnosis?

Comment: Do you have the reg key DisableStrictNameChecking (under ccs\services\Lanmanserver\parameters) set to 1?

Comment: No, we do not have that key at all.

Comment: Do you have a value called BackConnectionHostNames under CCS\Control\LSA\MSV1_0 ?

Comment: I cannot see that key either in our registry?

Comment: Do you have anything in the key: HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\Dnscache\Parameter\AlternateComputerNames? What is the output of the command 'setspn -l NEWNAME'?

Comment: @Rex HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\Dnscache\Parameter\AlternateComputerNames‌​ is empty. Running setspn -L newname only returns references to newname.

Comment: Do you have WINS in your environment?

Comment: We do not run a WINS server on our network.

Comment: Can you double-check `HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\LanmanServer\Parameters\OptionalNames`? I just followed your steps and found `OLDNAME` was still present in the output of `nbtstat`. I searched the registry for instances of `OLDNAME` and found three. I then renamed each to different unique values, rebooted, and ran `nbtstat` again. The value in `OptionalNames` is now in the output of `nbtstat` along with `NEWNAME`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll throw this in an answer just in case it slipped under the radar as a comment. Apologies ahead of time if you saw it already and it doesn't apply to your situation...

Can you double-check `HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\LanmanServer\Parameters\OptionalNames`? I just followed your steps and found `OLDNAME` was still present in the output of nbtstat. I searched the registry for instances of `OLDNAME` and found three. I then renamed each to different unique values, rebooted, and ran `nbtstat` again. The value in `OptionalNames` is now in the output of `nbtstat` along with `NEWNAME`. I was even able to add a tertiary name to the output of `nbtstat` by adding another value to `OptionalNames` (it's a REG_MULTI_SZ).

Answer (score 0):

The name entry might still be in dns. Try running the following command to remove the dns entry for you oldname.

```
dnscmd oldname.ourdomain.local /RecordDelete ourdomain.local oldname A 10.x.x.x
```

Check if the old name still exists after flushing the local DNS cache

```
ipconfig /flushdns
```

Answer (score 0):

What about running

```
NBTSTAT -RR
```

That should force a refresh/reregistration of netbios names over the network: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc784285(v=ws.10).aspx

Also, making sure that the computer account was renamed in AD, as I'm sure you've done.